# What's the proper way to convert a json.RawMessage to a struct?

Tags: json, go

I have this `struct`

```
type SyncInfo struct {
    Target string
}
```

Now I query some `json` data from ElasticSearch. `Source` is of type `json.RawMessage`.
All I want is to map `source` to my `SyncInfo` which I created the variable `mySyncInfo` for.

I even figured out how to do that...but it seems weird. I first call `MarshalJSON()` to get a `[]byte` and then feed that to `json.Unmarshal()` which takes an `[]byte` and a pointer to my struct.

This works fine but it feels as if I'm doing an extra hop. Am I missing something or is that the intended way to get from a `json.RawMessage` to a `struct`?

```
var mySyncInfo SyncInfo

jsonStr, _ := out.Hits.Hits[0].Source.MarshalJSON()
json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &mySyncInfo)

fmt.Print(mySyncInfo.Target)
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As said, the underlying type of `json.RawMessage` is `[]byte`, so you *can* use a `json.RawMessage` as the data parameter to `json.Unmarshal`.

However, your problem is that you have a pointer (`*json.RawMessage`) and not a value. All you have to do is to dereference it:

```
err := json.Unmarshal(*out.Hits.Hits[0].Source, &mySyncInfo)
```

**Working example:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type SyncInfo struct {
    Target string
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`{"target": "localhost"}`)
    Source := (*json.RawMessage)(&data)

    var mySyncInfo SyncInfo
    // Notice the dereferencing asterisk *
    err := json.Unmarshal(*Source, &mySyncInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", mySyncInfo)
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Target:localhost}
```

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/J8R3Qrjrzx

Comment: Welcome :) And happy Go coding!

Comment: You don't actually need to get the address of a variable only to dereference it 2 lines below. https://play.golang.org/p/75kvRlREPl- or even shorter: https://play.golang.org/p/kXMJchXM1CK

Answer (score 4):

`json.RawMessage` is really just a slice of bytes. You should be able to feed it directly into `json.Unmarshal` directly, like so:

```
json.Unmarshal(out.Hits.Hits[0].Source, &mySyncInfo)
```

Also, somewhat unrelated, but `json.Unmarshal` can return an error and you want to handle that.

```
err := json.Unmarshal(*out.Hits.Hits[0].Source, &mySyncInfo)
if err != nil {
    // Handle
}
```

Comment: This gives me a type error

`cannot use hit.Source (type *json.RawMessage) as type []byte in function argument`

Comment: Ah, we need to reference the value directly then. Try passing *json.RawMessage instead of json.RawMessage. I've updated the example in the answer to reflect this change.